# Problems with <headers.h> when using Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am trying to use R functions inside a C++ program. I downloaded the file  Rcpp_0.11.5.tar.gz from http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp/, unziped it and added the include directory to my IDE (I'm using Dev-C++ V5.4.2). First, I tried the following (just to check if it was ok):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Rcpp.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

During compilation, I got the following error:

C:\R\Rcpp\inst\include\Rcpp\r\headers.h [Error] R.h: No such file or directory

C:\R\Rcpp\inst\include\RcppCommon.h In file included from C:/Users/Gerson/Desktop/My Stuff/R/Rcpp/inst/include/RcppCommon.h

Inspecting the file RcppCommon.h, I found in line 48:

```
 #include <R.h>
```

But there is no such file in the package I unzipped. Looking further, I found other #include directives that point to files that didn't come in the package. Some examples:

```
#include <R_ext/Complex.h>
#include <R_ext/Parse.h>
#include <R_ext/Rdynload.h>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thks

GB

Comment: It is called Rcpp. But from your setup you want [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) instead.